# How can I groups numbers in a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, perl

I have a file with numbers in float format.
I can review them via `sort -rn numbers.txt | less`
I would like though to be able to "group" them. I.e. easily see how many are in the same range.
To give an example of the file:

```
30.9695041179657  
30.8851490020752  
30.2127060890198  
29.1361880302429  
26.4587681293488   
25.8535399436951   
25.7361891269684   
25.7305450439453   
25.1068568229675   
24.7598769664764   
24.3106801509857   
24.0782940387726
```

I don't care about accuracy. So I would like to know how many 25's are in the file e.g. in this case 4 and 30's etc for all numbers in the file.
So for this example an output like: 3 for 30, 1 for 29, 1 for 26, 4 for 25, 3 for 24.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

How about

```
cut -d. -f1 numbers.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Using your example data,

```
$ cut -d. -f1 numbers.txt | sort | uniq -c
      3 24
      4 25
      1 26
      1 29
      3 30
```

Comment: I'd make that `sort -n` to be on the safe side. +1, though.

Comment: @MyG, more like `sort -rn` if you've got to choose a particular sort order.

Answer (score 8):

With `awk` (`mawk`):

```
$ awk -F . '{COUNTS[$1]++} END{for(ct in COUNTS) {printf("%d %d time(s)\n", ct, COUNTS[ct])}}' test.txt
30 3 time(s)
24 3 time(s)
25 4 time(s)
26 1 time(s)
29 1 time(s)
```

The `-F` sets the field separator (`FS`) to `.`, other than that we go through all lines with the `{COUNTS[$1]++}`, using `$1` as the part before the decimal separator (`.`) and keeping a record of how many times we encounter them in an array named `COUNTS`.

At the end (`END {}`) we then dump what we found. As you can see the largest part is the output.

A bit more readable in a file:

```
{COUNTS[$1]++}
END {
  for(ct in COUNTS)
  {
    printf("%d %d time(s)\n", ct, COUNTS[ct])
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer - explaining the steps really improves the quality of the response.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk '{a[int($1)]++}END{for (i in a) {print a[i], i}}' inputfile
```

If you want the output to be sorted, pipe the output to `sort`:

```
awk '{a[int($1)]++}END{for (i in a) {print a[i], i}}' inputfile | sort -k2
```

For your sample input, this would produce:

```
3 24
4 25
1 26
1 29
3 30
```

Answer (score 4):

In `perl`:

```
perl -lan -F'\.' -e '$count{$F[0]}++;
    END{ 
        print "$_ --> $count{$_}" for sort {$a <=> $b} keys %count
    }' your_file
```

**Edit**

Probably more efficient:

```
perl -ne '
    $count{int()}++;
    END{ print "$_ --> $count{$_}" for sort {$a <=> $b} keys %count }'
your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your file has been sorted, so you can do like this:

```
$ uniq -c <(perl -pe 's/\.\d*//' file)
      3 30
      1 29
      1 26
      4 25
      3 24
```

If it has not been sorted:

```
$ uniq -c <(perl -pe 's/\.\d*//' file | sort -rn)
      3 30
      1 29
      1 26
      4 25
      3 24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -b-2 numbers.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

`cut -b-2` picks out the two first characters, `sort -nr` sorts the results by highest frequency first

Resulting output:

```
  4 25
  3 30
  3 24
  1 29
  1 26
```

Or as a python oneliner, just for the heck of it:

```
python -c 'l = [x[:2] for x in open("numbers.txt").readlines()];print(list(reversed(sorted([(l.count(x),x) for x in set(l)]))))'
```

Resulting output:

```
[(4, '25'), (3, '30'), (3, '24'), (1, '29'), (1, '26')]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A GNU coreutils + grep approach:

```
$ grep -oP '^\d+' file | sort | uniq -c
      3 24
      4 25
      1 26
      1 29
      3 30
```

The `-o` flag tells `grep` to print only the matching portion of the line and the `-P` activates Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which lets us use `\d` for numbers. So, the `grep` will print the longest stretch of digits found at the beginning of the line (i.e. everything up to the first non-digit, the `.`) and then `sort` sorts the output and `uniq -c` counts the number of occurences of each string in the input.

#### Another Perl approach:

```
$ perl -lne '/^\d+/ && $k{$&}++; END{print "$k{$_} : $_" for sort keys %k}' file 
3 : 24
4 : 25
1 : 26
1 : 29
3 : 30
```

The `$&` is the string matched in the previous match operation, so we store it in a hash (`%k`) and increment its value by one. The `END` block will print each number found (`$_`) and the value it has in the hash (`$k{$_}`), the number of times it was found.

#### And a bash (>=version 4) associative arrays approach:

```
$ while IFS='\.' read -r a b; do (( ll[$a]++ )); done <  file; 
    for i in ${!ll[@]} ; do echo ${ll[$i]} : $i; done
3 : 24
4 : 25
1 : 26
1 : 29
3 : 30
```

`IFS` set to `.` means that input lines are split into records on `.` so that `$a` will be the first digits up to the `.`. We iterate through them and use them as keys to an associative array whose value is increased each time the number is found. Then, once the array has been populated, we iterate through its list of keys (`${!ll[@]}`) and print each key and its value (the number of times it was seen).

Comment: Note that `coreutils` is a GNU software package containing a collection of utilities (merged the former GNU sh-utils, textutils, fileutils), `grep` is not part of that (it's packaged separately), and _coreutils_ has no particular meaning outside of GNU systems.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas fair enough, edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using [*GNU* `datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/)'s `bin` option:

```
datamash -s  bin:1 1 < num | datamash -s -g 1 count 1
```

Output:

```
24  3
25  4
26  1
29  1
30  3
```

Answer (score 0):

With [miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html):

```
$> mlr --from data.txt --ocsv put '$1=int(ceil($1))' then count-distinct -f 1
1,count
31,3
30,1
27,1
26,4
25,3
```